# Vagrant muulti-vm mode configure network

Tags: networking, vagrant

Does any one know how to configure multi-vm mode to be able to communicate each VM with others. I want to deploy client-server application and my VMs can't communicate **by dns** without adding hosts rules.

Comment: I found https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-hosts but I must use DHCP :( and I dont know IPs

Answer (score 0):

Put each VM in the same [private network](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html). If needed, have vagrant give them static IP addresses. For example

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
  end
end
```

Comment: same private network will allow to communicate by dns? I can't use static IPs

Comment: No, this does not automatically set up DNS for you. If you want to have Vagrant setup DNS look at https://github.com/phinze/landrush

Comment: I can set up host name just but pure vagrant like, vm.host_name = hostname + '.' + domain

But I need a way that will allow recognize vm each other by DNS